# Why do some people insist on creating a meeting, then send a URL — rather than simply clicking on the "Call" button?

Tags: communication, meetings

My corporation uses Microsoft Teams. If someone wants to schmooze with me — especially if it is 1 on 1 —   I ask them to click the "Call" button at the agreed time and date. See screenshot below. It feels unnecessary to create a meeting, then email the URL — waste of time!

[image: The Microsoft Teams "call" buttons interface, showing both an audio and video call option.]

But some people always create a meeting, then email you an URL. Why?

Comment: You do the same when you schedule a meeting. It's not like you can prevent it. The system sends out that link and that email automatically.

Comment: If I'm using the Teams client that is a webapp within Chrome, an ad hoc Call results in my audio not working. With a meeting I explicitly join it's fine. I don't know if it's just me but it seems unlikely...

Comment: How do you keep track of the agreed date and time if you don't schedule a meeting??

Comment: Why do you care how other people choose to do things? What impact does it have on you? How are you affected by their choices?

Comment: How do you go about blocking out that time so no-one else sets up a meeting then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a way they have the meeting in their calendars, get reminders and don't forget to join you by that time.

In Microsoft Teams, I can arrange a meeting as fast as I can set up a calendar event in Outlook, so why not have both issues covered at once?

Moreover, Microsoft Teams has features for meetings such as call recording, that are not available in 1:1 calls. Finally, it is easier to onboard somebody else in the call, if needed, by just sending them the meeting link or adding them.

Then, the planning and organization side, where you positively occupy a slot in your calendar so there is no chance of getting into something else by mistake.

Calls are meant for inmediate, likely short conversations. If it is something that must happen at a specific date and time, it may be because it takes a while (30-60 minutes...?), in such a situation, it is better to just arrange a formal meeting.

Answer (score 21):

Because they’re not animals.

Most people like to be able to plan their schedules.  This means having a block on everyone’s calendar for a meeting, so you (and others) know when you’re busy or not.

It takes less work, really, to choose a date and issue a meeting invite than anything else - the meeting is auto generated, the email is auto generated.

You are asking for something that is not customary, and is suboptimal, so you might well expect people don’t do it.

Comment: And it is also better for time tracking, having a list of all the meetings you had on your calendar instead of going through your chat to find when/why/for which project/... you had calls is so much easier

Answer (score 4):

From the tone of your post, I'm going to infer that you have a job where you enjoy the luxury of not having to do much planning for your day.  You may have assigned tasks that are not time sensitive in a down-to-the-minute fashion, that you complete at your own pace.  And you know what?  That's totally cool.

But other people you work with might not have that luxury, and spend a lot more time coordinating with others as a part of their jobs.  If this coordination is critical to the business, then **those people need to schedule those interactions** and not rely on the loosely-defined, almost impromptu meetings that you are suggesting.  You might be able to keep meeting time details in your head, but this doesn't mean that they can.

Try to see things from the other side.